# Upload html file to Tinymce read content and set content of editor

Tags: file-upload, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I will implement a function that display a file browser where i can upload a html file to read the html documents content and than past this content to editor.

How can i set a toolbar button that opens a file browser, that allows only html file uploads with max file size of 2MB.
Can i read content of file without to save it, like file_get_contents() on php.

Answer (score 1):

I created my own TinyMCE plugin for that.
If you don't know how plugins work, create a new folder named `htmlFileImport` under the TinyMCE `plugins` directory. If you are calling `tinymce.min.js`, then inside this folder create a file named `plugin.min.js`, otherwise name it `plugin.js` then paste this code inside

```js
tinymce.PluginManager.add('htmlFileImport', function(editor, url) {
  editor.addButton('htmlFileImport', {
    text: "Import HTML File",
    icon: false,
    onclick: function() {
      if(editor.getContent() == ""){
          editor.showFileDialog();
      }
      else{
        editor.showReplaceContentConfirmDialog();
      }
    }
  });
  editor.showReplaceContentConfirmDialog = function(){  
    eval(editor.dialogConfirmReplaceContentId).Open();
    eval(editor.dialogConfirmReplaceContentId).setzIndex(101);
  }
  editor.showInvalidHtmlFileDialod = function(){
      eval(editor.dialogInvalidHtmlFileId).Open();
      eval(editor.dialogInvalidHtmlFileId).setzIndex(101);
  }
  editor.showFileDialog = function(){
      var fileSelector = document.createElement('input');
      fileSelector.setAttribute('type', 'file');
      fileSelector.style.display = 'none';
      fileSelector.onchange = function(e) { 
        var file = fileSelector.files[0];
        if (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");

            reader.onload = function (event) {
                var bodyHtml = event.target.result;

                var bodyOpen = bodyHtml.indexOf('<body');
                if(bodyOpen == -1)
                    bodyOpen = bodyHtml.indexOf('< body');

                var bodyClose = bodyHtml.indexOf('</body>') + 6;
                if(bodyClose == -1)
                    bodyClose = bodyHtml.indexOf('</ body>') + 7;

                if(bodyOpen != -1 && bodyClose != -1){
                    bodyHtml = bodyHtml.substring(bodyOpen, bodyClose);
                    var divHtml = document.createElement('div');
                    divHtml.style.display = 'none';
                    divHtml.innerHTML = bodyHtml;
                    editor.setContent(divHtml.innerHTML);
                }
                else{
                    editor.showInvalidHtmlFileDialod();
                }
            }
            reader.onerror = function (evt) {
                editor.showInvalidHtmlFileDialod();
            }
        }
      };    
      fileSelector.click();
   }
});
```

`dialogConfirmReplaceContentId` and `dialogInvalidHtmlFileId` are custom properties I previously added to my editor in the `init` function, you will certainly have your own mechanism, but I let this code so you can understand what's going on.

Then to include this new plugin, just add it during your editor's creation by adding the configuration like this:

```js
tinymce.init({
    plugins: [
        'yourOtherPlugins htmlFileImport'
    ],
    toolbar1: 'yourOtherPlugins htmlFileImport',
    .....
});
```

For allowing only HTML file, you have no way to ensure the user will import this file's type. You can check if file name's extension is `.html` or `.htm` or you can do like I did: if I can't find any `<body>` tag inside then I consider this is not a valid HTML.

You can check the file size by simply calling `file.size`

You are new on StackOverflow so just to tell you that when you ask a question, you have to show that you tried something and did some research before posting. Here we don't post like if it was a simple Google search. We post question when we are stuck, after trying.